# ReactJS: Image Selector

Tags: html, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS ,I am developing a application where we display a List of Images from web  and User can select an image,enter some details and submit this image to Backend application. I am looking for React Component (possibly from Material UI -https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/grid-list/) where I can display a list of image and when clicking a image it show it as selected.I am looking something like Image Picker in Jquery (https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/).

Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, asking for libraries is explicitly off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

[react-image-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-picker) npm package.

There are also several react-native specific packages if your target platform is mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the info,This seems to have less traction in opensource community.